# How to invoke a browser via Java coding?

Tags: java, browser

I want to invoke a browser (e.g. Internet Explorer/Firefox/Google Chrome/Opera) via a Java interface. Also I need to pass some web links to this Java process. How to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "java interface"? And just to be sure: you're not talking about JavaScript, right?

Comment: Hi Bart .. via java coding ..yes i am not talking abt java script ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [desktop API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/):

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

This would launch a browser

Comment: can i use this API to invoke multiple weblinks? ..thats is i have given  - http://stackoverflow.com - i want to invoke with 5 links initially

Comment: I guess call the method 5 times?

Comment: but it will open a separate browser for each call ... but i want to open in the same browser with tabs . how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [`Desktop#browse()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html). It would however only launch the system default configured browser.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/) "**Opening the Browser**"

Answer (score 0):

You can run the browser executable as a separate process.

Click [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) link on how to execute an external process in Java.