# Invoking an HTML page from JAVA code

Tags: java, html

I am trying to invoke an HTML File stored on my desktop from inside a JAVA code as below.
I found this code snippet [here](http://getch.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/opening-an-external-html-file-through-a-java-code/)

```
       try
        {
            Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
            String url = "C:\\Users\\Rana\\Desktop\\test.html";
            String browser ="C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe ";
            Process p = r.exec(browser);
            p.waitFor();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried using backslash and forward slashes, both. But it is throwing this error in both case....

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at package1.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:376)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
```

The path "browser" is present.
Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: the first line says `Cannot run program C:/Program` -- which isn't what you are trying to run. I think the space in the path is making it not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734424/how-to-invoke-a-browser-via-java-coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the space in your path to the browser.  The system thinks you are trying to run a program called "C:/Program" with "Files/Mozilla" and "Firefox/firefox.exe" as the arguments.  Try adding quotes around the exe name:

```
String browser ="\"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\" ";
```

To incorporate SnakeDoc's advice, you could use the environment variable to take care of the portion of the path down to "Program Files", but you will still need the quotes to take care of any other spaces in the path:

```
String browser = "\"" + System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)") + "Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"";
```

Comment: or: `String browser = System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)") + "Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe";`

Comment: Cool - didn't know there was an environment variable for Program Files.  Might still have a problem with the space between "Mozilla" and "Firefox", correct?

Comment: not sure actually... i like using environment vars whenever possible, helps make my program more dynamic with less static/hard-coded things.

Comment: Agree - Definitely advocate the use of the env var - you may just have to quote the whole thing when you are done...

Comment: right, which should be easy like;   `String browser = "\"" + System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)") + "Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"";`

Comment: @SnakeDoc - incorporated advice into answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the system properties:

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
```

or

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Better advice,

use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) for such tasks.You should give it a try.I promise you would definitely find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the 32bit version browser should be `String browser ="C:/Program Files(x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe ";`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String browser ="\"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"";
```

There is problem with space in Program files that get treated as separator if not inside Quotes. It is briliant idea by Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to do this with `java.awt.Desktop`

```
File htmlFile = new File("C:" + File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "theuser" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Test.html");
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);
}
```